# Check id NSNumber is null

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is my code:

```
if (userLatPosition != nil) {
    CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[userLatPosition floatValue] longitude:[userLongPosition floatValue]];
    [self getLocationTextForUserIndex:j withLocation:userLocation];
}
```

When it's about to run, this is what I see for userLatPosition:

```
userLatPosition = (NSNumber *) 0x02ab6678 (null)
```

One would think the if statement should be false and it would skip over the if but for some reason it does get into the if lines…

Does someone knows why? What's the proper check for (null) in NSNumbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `userLatPosition` is `NSNull`, not `nil`. Note that `NSNull` isn't equal to `nil`, it's a placeholder to indicate a `nil` value which can be stored in containers like `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, which don't accept `nil` values.

A check would look like this:

```
if(userLatPosition && userLatPosition != [NSNull null])
{
}
```

See also: [Using NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html)

Comment: So how would the check look like?